# Bonjour (Printing service) run on Sleep

Tags: network, sleep-wake, printing, bonjour

I currently use Bonjour for my home wireless printing. It works flawlessly, but I have one gripe with software. If my iMac (pc connected to the printer) goes to sleep, the wireless print stops. Is there anyway if the printing can work while the mac sleeps. I understand why Apple did this to conserve power, but my iMac is always connected to power, and running things on the background. Any help, greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep wireless printing available, you need to stop your Mac from sleeping.

To disable sleep on Mac OS X:

1. Launch **System Preferences.app** from the **Applications** folder.
2. Select **Energy Saver**
3. Move the **Computer sleep:** slider to **Never**.

[image: System Preferences]